# Best practice to identify an UIImageView in a NSMutableArray?

Tags: iphone, indexing

I am going to `addObject` of 8 `UIImageView *` to a `NSMutableArray`. Each `UIImageView` is User Interaction Enabled.

When a user touches one of the `UIImageView`s, what is the best way to recall the index position of the selected `UIImageView' in the`NSMutableArray`?

I can imagine:

- sub-class `UIImageView` and add a `NSUInteger` index attribute
- traverse the `NSMutableArray` and compare each `UIImageView *` pointer

Is there an better alternative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setting a tag would be the easiest way: [myImageView setTag:anIdentifier]; 
you could set the tag number as the same as the index in the array.

Or you could search for your imageView object in the array every time you need it:
[myarray indexOfObject:myImageView];